# DXA 1.8 Java web app looking the VariantId='Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA' but content service is returning only the VariantId='WyNkZWYjXQ=='

Tags: dxa, content-delivery, web8.5, dxa-1.8, content-service

We're upgrading DXA 1.5 to 1.8; We're facing an issue web app throws a null exception below error message when try to call this URL this **/system/config/_all.json**

```
2018-12-21 10:26:26,297 DEBUG DefaultContentProvider - Writing binary content to file: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\wtpwebapps\dxaWeb\BinaryData\826\system\config\_all.json
2018-12-21 10:26:26,327 ERROR PageController - Exception while processing request for: /
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.DefaultContentProvider.getStaticContentFile(DefaultContentProvider.java:95)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider.getStaticContentFile(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:366)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider.getStaticContent(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:309)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.parseJsonFileTree(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:239)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.loadMainConfiguration(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.createLocalization(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.createLocalization(AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.java:101)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.getLocalization(AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.java:68)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.localization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:205)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.getLocalization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:85)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2bfec188.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fbe4fc14.getLocalization(<generated>)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:914)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Note:**

I can see the **_all.json** binary content in broker db but not getting response on content sevice.

If I pull the `BinaryContents` `http://domain:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents` service collection via postman: http://www.filedropper.com/binarycontents I do not see the `VariantId: Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA` & `BinaryId = 216112 -> core component` related data but I can see the response  has some `VariantId='WyNkZWYjXQ=='` related data

Any suggestion, why my content service is not returning this `VariantId: Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA` & `BinaryId = 216112 -> core component`

**Updated:**

I have tried unpublished/published the "`Publish Settings and Publish HTML Design`" pages

**Content service Request**:

> http://domain:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents(BinaryId=216112,PublicationId=826,VariantId='Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA==')/$value`

**Postman response:**

```
"Unable to build binary entry: No resource was found for the requested item`"
```

**DXAWeb App TRACE log:** http://www.filedropper.com/cdcore2018-12-21

Comment: Please edit your question and update if there any exception error messages in Web App and Content service

Comment: Thanks Vel. I have added the dxaWeb app debug log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure CD Deployer(cd_storage_conf.xml) is configured to store Binaries on the CD Content Store (database) instead of file system.

Example:

```
<Publication Id="826" cached="false" defaultStorageId="EXPreviewDB">
    <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".jsp" storageId="EXPreviewDB" typeMapping="Page"/>
    <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".json" storageId="EXPreviewDB" typeMapping="Binary"/>
    <Item cached="true" storageId="EXPreviewDB" typeMapping="Binary"/>
</Publication>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear to me what exactly you're trying to do and what is your expected output.

For my understanding, you have upgraded your DXA web app from DXA 1.5 to DXA 1.8 with web-8.5 and your web app not getting downloaded your publish settings media system config files.

eg: \BinaryData\826\system\config_all.json

Try this below URL using postman to check **/system/config/_all.json** page binary content exist in broker DB or not?

```
http://domain:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents(BinaryId=216112 ,PublicationId=826,VariantId='Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA==')/$value
```

If this API call gets the response then no issue with broker DB, something wrong in your migrated DXA web application.

If this API call not getting the response then your _System->**Publish Settings** page not published to your broker DB.

Try unpublish and republish this page to check, enable your web app log file to **TRACE**  to troubleshoot and keep it posted your findings and TRACE logs

**Updated:**

It seems to look like your CD Deployer is configured to store Binaries on the file system instead of in the CD Content Store (database).

Double check your broker-db for that binary content exists in the DB or not by running this select query in your broker db?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [BINARY_CONTENT] WHERE PUBLICATION_ID = 826 AND BINARY_ID=216112 AND VARIANT_ID = 'config-bootstrap'
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Velmurugan for your response. I'm sorry for the bit confused question. I have updated my question with more details now but you were understood my question correctly.  I have tried all your suggestion and I provided my update in my question.

Comment: Your web app logs were useful, that explains what happened, see the updated section in the answer

Comment: Thanks Vel. Your select query has return the data and I can see the "content" column:  {  
   "defaultLocalization":true,
   "staging":true,
   "mediaRoot":"$BINARY_DOMAIN$/media",
   "siteLocalizations":[  
      {  
         "Id":"826",
         "Path":"/",
         "Language":"English",
         "IsMaster":true
      }
   ],
   "files":[  
      "/system/config/core.taxonomies.json",
      "/system/config/core.json",
      "/system/config/core.schemas.json",
      "/system/config/nationwide.schemas.json",
      "/system/config/nationwide.templates.json"
   ]
}

Comment: Enable content-service logs to **TRACE** to look at what's going on why you getting this "Unable to build binary entry: No resource was found for the requested item"

Comment: you were right Vel. I found the cause is one of the server cd_storage_conf.xml  was not configured properly. thanks for all your input.